# Replacing negatives to positives and vice versa in a String

Tags: java, string

Let's say I have a String representation of an equation like -

> (1 -2 3) v (-1 3 2) v (-5 1 4) v (-4 -2 -3) v (-3 4 5) v (1 -2 5) v (3 -2 5) v (2 3 -4)

And I have a method that takes the string to be modified, the numeric variable to be replaced and the state to which it should be set as

```
public String changedString(String original, int num, boolean state) {

}
```

Which for a call as

```
changedString(original, 2, false);
```

should return the following string

> (1 2 3) v (-1 3 -2) v (-5 1 4) v (-4 2 -3) v (-3 4 5) v (1 2 5) v (3 2 5) v (-2 3 -4)

Notice that all negation instances of 2 (negative 2s) have been changed to positive instances whereas the positive instances of 2 (positive 2s) have been changed to negative instances.

In order to approach this problem, I initially tried `String.replaceAll()` which obviously would not work. An alternative approach I tried was -

```
public String changedString (String original,int num, boolean state){
        String temp = original;
        if (!state) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(temp);
            //Following code changes negative instances to positives
            String from = "-" + num;
            String to = "" + num;
            int index = sb.indexOf("-" + num);
            while (index != -1) {
                sb.replace(index, index + from.length(), to);
                index += to.length();
                index = sb.indexOf(from, index);
            }

            //Following code changes positive instances to negatives
            from = "" + num;
            to = "-" + num;
            index = sb.indexOf("-" + num);
            while (index != -1) {
                sb.replace(index, index + from.length(), to);
                index += to.length();
                index = sb.indexOf(from, index);
            }
            temp = sb.toString();
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

However, the problem again with this alternative approach is that it always converts any given number to negative. How can I do it easier and more efficiently?

(This is a element in my approach to attempt a Boolean Satisfiability Problem)

Comment: Couldn't you use replaceAll, and replace `"-"+num` with `num` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, which `String.replaceAll()` supports. The catch is that you would have to use a temporary character to indicate which numbers are switching state first:

```
public String changedString(String original, int num, boolean state)
{
    String str = original.replaceAll("-" + num + "(?!\\d)", "#" + num);
    str = str.replaceAll("(?<![#0-9])" + num + "(?!\\d)", "-" + num);
    str = str.replaceAll("#" + num + "(?!\\d)", num);
    return str; 
}
```

This replaces all occurences of `-num` with `#num`, then all occurences of `num` with `-num` and then `#num` with `num`. The first step avoids the pitfall of doing `-num`->`num` to remove the negatives, then converting all occurences to `-num`.

These regexes use lookaround to ensure that the number is delimited properly without capturing the delimiters. You can read more on lookaround here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html and look up the Java syntax here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special.